# Difference between Azure Resources API and Storage API

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-api-management

I am trying to access logs in Azure blob storage. Here I saw I can use both Resources API and Storage Services API to access them.

Can somebody please explain the advantages and disadvantages of using one over another.

Comment: Which the docs you are looking at?

Answer (score 0):

That APIs have different purpose:

- [Azure Storage Resource Provider REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/) we should use for managing storage like a resource. You can see all your resources in this link: [Azure resources](https://resources.azure.com/)
- [Azure storage Service REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/) we use for managing like a service. If you take a look that have a different method to manage.

Also, you can give to user different roles for user. And you have a to control who can do and what.